# In my Datatable, I have a simple column containing only simple strings but it's not sorting correctly

Tags: sorting, datatable

I have a really simple Datatable. Every columns are sorting correctly except one. This columns contain only text (string).
Here's the order I get when I sort the column:

```
À publier,
Retiré temporairement,
Retiré - Rejet
Nouveau.
```

Here's the code for the Datatable, as you can see, it's quite simple.
var peutModifier = $('#hdnPeutModifier').val();

```
if (peutModifier !== 'undefined' && peutModifier === 'True') {
    colonneAvecTriDesactive = [0, -1]; // Tri désactivé sur première et dernière colonne.
} else {
    colonneAvecTriDesactive = [-1]; // Tri désactivé sur dernière colonne.
}

$('#DataTablePublication').DataTable({
    search: false,
    bFilter: false,
    pageLength: 100,
    lengthMenu: [[10, 20, 50, 100], [10, 20, 50, 100]],
    columnDefs: [
        { orderable: false, targets: colonneAvecTriDesactive }
    ],
    order: [],
    language: {
        paginate: {
            first: "Premier",
            last: "Dernier",
            next: "Suivant",
            previous: "Précédent"
        }
    }
});
```

I checked and the column contains only strings, also, I have not set any trigger on the column sorting and I don't have any errors in my browser.

Does someone have an idea about this problem?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. *"Here's the order I get when I sort the column: À publier, Retiré temporairement, Retiré - Rejet Nouveau."* And what order did you expect?

Comment: Also, which language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you have sorted your column in *reverse* alphabetical order - which is why `À` appears first (since `À` follows `z,` using default codepoint sorting).

To use language-sensitive sorting, i.e. the sort order that you would expect to find in a dictionary (where `église` follows `eagle`, not `zebra`), you can use the DataTables [internationalization plug-in](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/intl).

Steps to use:

1. Add the library to the `<head>` section of your page. You can use a CDN for this:

   `<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.0/sorting/intl.js"></script>`
2. Initialize the plug-in in your script, before you create your DataTable:

   `$.fn.dataTable.ext.order.intl();`

You can also provide an explicit locale if you want to:

`$.fn.dataTable.ext.order.intl('fr');`

There are various additional configuration options described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl).

Comment: You were right, it solved my problem. I never had to use this before because I never had a column starting with special character. Thanks again.